# How to debug a console Hangman program?

Tags: javascript

This program takes sentence as user input. Then it randomly selects word of hangman game. After user is asked to enter letters one by one. I believe there is something wrong with my function `guess`. It does not behave like I wanted to.

Guess function suppose to do `guess(letter)`. If letter hasn't been tried already, push the letter tried into the array of guessedLetters and decrease guesses by 1. Loop through currentWord to see if letter is a match. If it is, assign letter to appropriate spots in hangmanWord.

If isOver returns true, invoke overMessage, else invoke render, prompt a new letter *and* invoke guess with that letter (using recursion).

```
var numOfGuesses;
var gueesedLetters = []
var currentWord = ''
var hangmanWord = []
var letter;

function guess(letter) {
    if (gueesedLetters.indexOf(letter) === -1) {
        gueesedLetters.push(letter);
        numOfGuesses--;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
            if (letter === currentWord[i]) {
                var currWrdIndex = currentWord.indexOf(letter)
                hangmanWord.splice(currentWord[i], 0, letter)
            }
        }
    }


    if (isOver() === true) {
        overMessage();
    } else {
        console.log(render());
        letter = prompt("Please enter the letter").toLowerCase();
        guess(letter);
    }
}


function isOver() {
    if (currentWord.split("").sort().join("") === hangmanWord.sort().join("") || numOfGuesses === 0) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

function overMessage() {
    if (currentWord.split().sort().join("") === hangmanWord.sort().join("")) {
        return "You win";
    } else if (numOfGuesses === 0) {
        return "You lose";
    } else {
        return "Game is not over";
    }
}

function render() {
    console.log("The hangman word was %s", currentWord);
    console.log("The total number of guesses are %s", numOfGuesses);
    console.log("Total guess letters are %s", gueesedLetters);

}


function startGame(wordsArray) {
    numOfGuesses = 10;
    gueesedLetters = []
    currentWord = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)]
    letter = prompt("Please enter the letter ?")
    guess(letter);
}

function mainProgram() {
    var userSentence = prompt("Please enter sentences to begin.")
    userSentence = userSentence.split(" ")
    startGame(userSentence)
    if (isOver() === true) {
        console.log(overMessage())
        console.log(render())
    }
}

mainProgram()
```

Comment: Does this program need to be recursive, either for operational or educational reasons? It seems to me that you can solve this problem without recursion.

Comment: @halfer -- I don't think someone trying to learn to debug basic programs needs to be worried about flattening recursion yet.

Comment: @gbtimmon: I wasn't suggesting it for reasons of polish - I think their task will be very much simplified if the recursion can be taken out.

Comment: @supritshah1289 You are on the right path.... I picked your code up and ran it in JS fiddle and I could figure out the error based on the console output. I chrome I can view that output by hitting f12 the navigating to Console. What are you seeing in the console output.

Comment: @halfer That's not always true for someone who is new.